# How do you get Ingredients to evolve creatures in Card Wars Kingdom

Tags: card-wars-kingdom

Pretty much what's in the title, during the tutorial you're told that you can evolve creatures so you can continue to increase their stats but they require ingredients as opposed to cake. Where do I find these ingredients?

Answer (score 1):

You find it in the dungeon, the title of each battle is the ingredient you are getting, what i'm missing here is the name of the ingredient that you need on the evolve section, i had to guess what the pictures were